# Gitbash ssh to git@github.com，raised port 22: Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: git, github, ssh

Enter gitbash & run then I got:

```
ssh -T git@github.com

socket: Socket operation on non-socket

ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Socket operation on non-socket
```

How is it?

I can't find the troubleshooting in github sites via https://help.github.com/categories/ssh/

Comment: What OS are you on, and what git version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem too, and I've just solved this problem by switching to install a 32-bit Git. As for why 64-bit Git does not work, I don't figure out yet.
By the way, I'm using the latest Git(version 2.6.4) on Windows 10.